# SSRS 2012: Display Parameter Label in Caps

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2012

The parameter has many values but the labels can either be all caps or all lowercase. How can I make the report to always display the label in the header from the selected parameter value all in CAPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the function `UCase`.  It returns a string or characters containing the specified string converted to uppercase.

To set your parameter to all capitals, try:

```
=UCASE(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Label)
```

Comment: ^ this, unless by header you mean the actual parameter drop down. In that case you'd have to set them to uppercase in your query for the dataset (assuming you're parameter is based on a dataset).

Comment: No, it's just to display in the report header